# Deleting archived data based on 30 days data range

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, archiving

I have 2 sql instance in a server. 
1 named TRC (online db) another one TRC_ARC (archiving db).

I have successfully transfer 30 days data based on oldest EntryDate from TRC to TRC_ARC.

The query is

```
use TRC_ARC
--T_TRC_AssyPoka Table
declare @MaxNo datetime = (select max(EntryDate) from T_TRC_AssyPoka) --date max current archived table
insert into TRC_ARC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka --destination
select * from TRC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka --source
where EntryDate > @MaxNo --source entrydate > date max current archived table
and DateDiff(D, @MaxNo, EntryDate) < 30 -- date range 30 days
```

How do I delete the archived 30 days data from TRC? Because i have tried using below query but it returns different row affected.

```
use TRC_ARC
--T_TRC_AssyPoka Table
declare @MaxNo datetime = (select max(EntryDate) from T_TRC_AssyPoka) --date max current archived table
**delete from TRC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka** --destination
select * from TRC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka --source
where EntryDate > @MaxNo --source entrydate > date max current archived table
and DateDiff(D, @MaxNo, EntryDate) < 30 -- date range 30 days
```

Comment: Well if the underlying data in the `T_TRC_AssyPoka` table could be changing (i.e. new records coming or some other process deleting records), then the number of target records could be different.

Comment: Dear Tim, the table doesn't have any transactions during the archiving activity because of plant shutdown. So i'm very sure there is no new records coming.

Comment: Your `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` is the using _same_ table, `T_TRC_AssyPoke` for both the _source_ and _destination_.  I'm pretty sure you meant to copy from `T_AssyPoka` to `T_TRC_AssyPoka`.

Comment: What's the database? Looks like SQL Server or Sybase.

Comment: Tim, it is the same name table, but different source because different sql instance. I mean that source table data (TRC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka) that have been archived to archiving table(TRC_ARC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka) is deleted from the source table exactly as archived.

Comment: Dear The Impaler, SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Doesn't max(EntryDate) from TRC_ARC.T_TRC_AssyPoka change due to the INSERT?

Comment: sticky bit, yes you're right! i'm currently testing in my development server updated query

Comment: This isn't something you want to use dates for explicitly unless there is no chance the date can be duplicated ever. Instead, use the primary key. Even better, use LOG shipping or mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

```
use TRC_ARC
--T_TRC_AssyPoka Table
declare @MaxNo datetime = (select max(EntryDate) from T_TRC_AssyPoka) --date max current archived table
**delete from TRC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka** --destination
select * from TRC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka --source
where EntryDate > @MaxNo --source entrydate > date max current archived table
and DateDiff(D, @MaxNo, EntryDate) < 30 -- date range 30 days
```

According to your above description, my understanding is that you would like to delete the rows which has been inserted into table 'TRC_ARC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka'. Right?

If so , you can try following script.

```
use TRC_ARC
    --T_TRC_AssyPoka Table
    declare @MaxNo datetime = (select max(EntryDate) from T_TRC_AssyPoka) --date max current archived table
    delete from TRC.dbo.T_TRC_AssyPoka
    where EntryDate > @MaxNo --source entrydate > date max current archived table
    and DateDiff(D, @MaxNo, EntryDate) < 30 -- date range 30 days
```

Best Regards,

Rachel

Comment: Thanks for the help Rachel. I will try this and inform if OK